# Disable a specific set of snippets in SnipMate

Tags: snippets, plugin-snipmate

Is it possible to tell SnipMate to ignore a specific set of snippets?

Let's take `vim-snippets/snippets/javascript/javascript-jquery.snippets` as an example. When editing a JavaScript file, all snippet files matching `vim-snippets/snippets/javascript/*.snippets` are being loaded.

As I do not use jQuery, I don't want the jQuery snippets to be loaded. Is there some way to make SnipMate load only the files that I want it to load, or exclude the files that I don't want?

Googling this has not led to a solution.